# Testing whether a function is continuous at a specific point

Tags: limits, continuity

If we want to test whether a function is continuous at a specific point (for example $f(x)=x+5$ at $x=3$), should we test whether $\lim_{x\to 3^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 3^+}f(x)=f(3)$?
That is just the first possibility, because the second possibility is to test whether $\lim_{x\to 3}f(x)=f(3)$.
Which one of the possibilities should I choose?

Comment: _If_ the limits exists, than the right limit equals to the left limit, and both of them are equal the _the_ limit. In this instance, since $f$ is a polynomial, the limit exists, and the function is continuous.

Comment: which one of the two possibities in my case ?

Comment: i know that the funciton is continuous but i mean how to express that ? ..like the first possibility or the seond ?

Comment: I would use the second one since it is shorter. Do note that sometimes we _can_ prove a limit exists by showing that the right limit equals to the left limit, so it might help you practice that.